# Sounds realization in js game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I was making a simple game in clear js and I have a question about optimization.

So what I need is to keep the music and sounds separately and I have two variants:

1. Music is an Audio-object and Sounds are a list of Audio-objects for every sound. In that way I have to change (for example) the volume of every sound if it's needed:

```
let music_player = new Audio('some src');

let sounds = {
  kick: new Audio('some src'),
  jump: new Audio('some src'),
  run: new Audio('some src')
  //there can be more sounds
};

window.addEventListener('click', function(){
  music_player.play();
  sounds.jump.play();
  sounds.kick.play();
});
```

2. Music didn't change but Sounds are the one Audio-object now and if I want to play different sounds i have to change the source of it. It can also be the class of SoundPlayer:

```
let music_player = new Audio('some src');
let sound_player = new Audio('some src');

//list of sounds with their sources
let sounds = {
  kick:'some src',
  jump:'some src',
  run:'some src'
};

function sound_play(sound){
  sound_player.src = sound;
  sound_player.play();
}

window.addEventListener('click', function(){
  music_player.play();
  sound_play(sounds.jump);
  sound_play(sounds.kick);
});
```

What is the best way in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear .. it's not explained enough ..

But let's try to help ..

---

If you used `new Audio("src")` then you have an audio in your javascript now ..

But you must know that you cannot `play()` it until the user interacts with your dom ..

So I will suppose that the user interacts with the dom now to explain the next:

- Use `anyAudio.play()` to play the audio
- Use `anyAudio.pause()` to pause the audio
- Use `anyAudio.paused` to check if the audio is paused or not
- Use `anyAudio.currentTime` to get or set the current time the audio on
- Use `anyAudio.playbackRate` to get and set the speed of the audio `default: 1`
- Use `anyAudio.volume` to get and set the volume of the audio `default: 1`

Let's say you want to create a function that gets an audio from a list of sounds and play it with a specific volume :

```
let sound_player = new Audio("")
let sounds = {
    kick:'some src',
    jump:'some src',
    run:'some src'
}
function sound_play(sound, volume){
    sound_player.src = sound
    sound_player.volume = volume || 1
    sound_player.play()
}
```

now your function is ready , but again, be sure to run it after the user interacts with the dom, because it's not going to work if the user didn't interact with dom.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I knew it. I made a big mistake by not writing the user interaction in my examples. I wanted to make them as simple as possible and forgot about that. I also understand methods of the Audio object and how to change the volume. Anyway thank you very much for correcting my dumb question)

The thing I don't understand is should I create many Audio-objects for every sound or just the one object and change the source of it every time?

Comment: If I am creating this task, I will create new `Audio` object every time, because maybe anytime through your game you will need to use two or more sounds at the same time, so you must have an `Audio` object for every new sound.